# /usr/bin/open executable disappeared

Tags: terminal, mac, command-line, high-sierra

I am on macOS High Sierra (Version 10.13.3) all recent updates are installed.
The `open` executable is not in the `/usr/bin` folder anymore.

Is there anyway to repair the system so that I can get it again?
I have no clue how this happened in the first place, maybe after the last macOS update. Did I miss something in their release notes?

To clarify, this is not a path issue, the executable just is not there anymore.

Comment: Do you have SIP disabled?

Comment: @patrix no, it is disabled.

Comment: If SIP is disabled I suspect a user error. To recover just reinstall the OS from the recovery partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SIP was disabled there is a high chance this was a user error on my side like the comments suggested. I did not want to do a complete reinstall due to all the hassle that would ensue.

This problem ended up getting fixed by itself when the next macOS update was released. After installing the update the `open` executable was back at its original place.

Hope this helps people encountering a similar issue.